# Algebra calculus, solve for x and y

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have two equations:

> $-2x(y^3+1)=0 \implies x=0, \; y=-1, $

and

> $y(8-3x^2y)=0 \implies x= \pm \sqrt{8/3y}, \;  y=0.$

I can "see" that the only solution is when $x=y=0$, but I really can't explain it with algebra.

Can anyone give me a hint:)

Answer (score 1):

If $y=-1$, then the second equation becomes $-(8+3x^2)=0$. This is impossible, right?! But then $x=0$ and so…

Comment: Hi professor Santos, could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3668359/if-fa-rightarrow-bbbrn-is-a-bijection-such-that-f-in-cr-and-detdx?noredirect=1#comment7538524_3668359)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming everything here is real-valued. In $\mathbb{R}$ there is this nice property:

\begin{equation}
\text{If } ab = 0, \text{ then either } a = 0 \text{ or } b = 0. 
\end{equation}

So if $-2x(y^3 + 1) = 0$, either $-2x = 0$ or $y^3 + 1 = 0$. Likewise for the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose on the contrary that $y=-1$, then we have

$$8+3x^2=0$$ but $8+3x^2>0$. Hence we rule out $y=-1$.

Hence we must have $x=0$, substituing that in the second equation and you can solve for $y$ and find that it is $0$.

[image]

$y=-1$ doesn't intersect with $y(8-3x^2y)=0$.